# INJECT_EVENTS permission in appium Test

Tags: appium

I am getting below error on running touchaction using appium on real device:

> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"status":13,"value":"Injecting to another application requires INJECT_EVENTS permission"}
>   info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":13,"value":{"message":"An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.","origValue":"Injecting to another application requires INJECT_EVENTS permission"},">